# find by method return value in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a method in model , that method return some value. I want to search by which applications have `min_loan = 1000` like, how to ? any one suggest.

Note: Here `min_loan` is not a column.

Ex:
 `Application.first.min_loan  #=> 0`

```
Application.where(:min_loan => 1000)  #=> error

def min_loan
  #return some value
end
```

Thanks Prasad.

Comment: see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.min_loan(val)
  where("loan > ?", val)
end

#assuming that loan is the column name
```

Then call

```
Application.min_loan(1000)
```

It will return applications have min_loan = 1000